# CSV data from URL

Tags: f#

## Data

Here's a chart of the Federal Reserve Balance sheet assets:

[image]

Link:

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/WALCL

## Script

The following F# script will retrieve the series data and display it:

```
#r "nuget: CsvHelper, 30.0.1"

open System.IO
open System.Net.Http
open CsvHelper

type WALCLRecord() =
    member val DATE = "" with get, set
    member val WALCL = "" with get, set

let uri = sprintf  "https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?id=%s&cosd=%s" "WALCL" "2023-01-01"
        
let str = (new HttpClient()).GetStringAsync(uri).Result

use string_reader = new StringReader(str)
use csv_reader = new CsvReader(string_reader, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

let records = csv_reader.GetRecords<WALCLRecord>()

let arr = records |> Array.ofSeq

for elt in arr do
    printfn "%10s %15s" elt.DATE elt.WALCL
```

Result:

```
2023-03-15       8639300.0                                                                                                                                                                               
2023-03-22       8733787.0                                                                                                                                                                               
2023-03-29       8705942.0                                                                                                                                                                               
2023-04-05       8632384.0                                                                                                                                                                               
2023-04-12       8614797.0                                                                                                                                                                               
2023-04-19       8593263.0                                                                                                                                                                               
2023-04-26       8562768.0                                                                                                                                                                               
2023-05-03       8503994.0                                                                                                                                                                               
2023-05-10       8503017.0                                                                                                                                                                               
2023-05-17       8456760.0                                                                                                                                                                               
2023-05-24       8436255.0
```

## Question

I used `CsvHelper` because that's what I'm familiar with.

However, I see that `FSharp.Data` is popular and has CSV support.

Is there a way to implement the above using `FSharp.Data` and not have to go through a temporary file to specify the format? The example on the site uses the type provider with example data in a file. I'd like to avoid having to provide example data in a file.

Also, in the above script, I used a class with properties for `WALCLRecord` in order to be compatible with CsvHelper. I'd prefer to use something like this instead:

```
type WALCLRecord = {
    DATE : string
    WALCL : float
}
```

but CsvHelper didn't play well with that. So that's another reason I'd like to see if `FSharp.Data` is an option.

Comment: Since you know the data returned is always two fields separated by a comma, and the fields are not quoted, why not just split on the commas, rather than use a type provider?

Answer (score 3):

The nice thing about type providers is that they can automatically generate the `WALCLRecord` type for you, so you do not have to define it. This is great for simple scripts (for larger applications, you'd want to have a domain model that you fully control, though).

A solution using F# data looks like this

```cs
#r "nuget:FSharp.Data"
open FSharp.Data

// Generate a provided type, based on a sample URL
type StFedCsv = CsvProvider<"https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?id=WALCL&cosd=2023-01-01">

// Load actual data at runtime, using possibly 
// different URL (with the same format)
let records = StFedCsv.Load(sprintf  "https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?id=%s&cosd=%s" "WALCL" "2023-01-01")

// Iterate over the rows - not that `DATE` is inferred 
// as `DateTime` and `WALCL` is inferred as `decimal`
for elt in records.Rows do
    printfn "%A %A" elt.DATE elt.WALCL
```

Comment: Thank you Tomas.  Is there a way to define the type myself and have FSharp.Data use it?

Comment: @dharmatech No, that's not possible. The type providers are designed to generate the types for you. If you want to define the type yourself, then another tool will serve you better.

Comment: Thank you Tomas, for answering my questions so patiently. 